std::cout makes SwiftUI crash
I'm making a "Hello World" app in C++ in Xcode and I call C++ from Swift via Objective-C++ bridge but whenever I use std::cout more than once it always crashes:
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl; // This alone prints the message to the console.
    // std::cout << "test" << std::endl; // Uncommenting this will print neither message.

    return 0;
}

void startMain() {
    main();
}

Bridge.h:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bridge : NSObject

+ (void) startCpp;

@end

Bridge.mm:
extern void startMain();

@implementation Bridge

+ (void) startCpp {
    startMain();
}

@end

MyApp.swift:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear(perform: test)
        }
    }
    
    func test() {
        Bridge.startCpp()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

The error for SwiftUI is Thread 1: Fatal error: SwiftUI/AppGraph.swift:23: Fatal error: AppGraph.shared may only be set once!.
The error if I switch to the old AppDelegate is Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1234...)
I tried running C++ in another thread via Swift and C++ (running main() in detached thread) but both didn't work either.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Calling main() result in undefined behavior.

[basic.start.main] - "The function main shall not be used within a program." - ... and "used" means that you are not allowed to call it as @3CxEZiVlQ pointed out. What happens if you move your code to the startMain function?

Some reading on the above comment: Why are you not allowed to call the main function?

Thank you, I renamed the function and it seems to work now. I didn't know about these resources, I'll make sure to read them, I started using C++ and Xcode 2 days ago.

Be really careful with C++. It rarely rewards guesses, so some amount of structured book-learning is highly recommended when you are starting out. Don't try to learn by reading the Language Standard; it's written more for folks writing compilers than for students.
